# not able to read from kafka using strom cluster

Tags: apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api, apache-zookeeper

I am running Strom cluster where 2 supervisor and 1 nimbus is running. Where I am reading from kafka with topic id "topic1". But on UI I am getting below error

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/topic1/partitions at storm.kafka.DynamicBrok

and worker_*.log showing below error.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/app/storm/supervisor/stormdist/airpushTop-1-1431081661/stormconf.ser' does not exist
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:299) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1763) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at backtype.storm.config$read_supervisor_storm_conf.invoke(config.clj:212) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$worker_data.invoke(worker.clj:182) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5033$exec_fn__1754__auto____5034.invoke(worker.clj:398) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5033$mk_worker__5089.doInvoke(worker.clj:389) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:500) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
2015-05-08T17:09:19.209+0530 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error on initialization")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error on initialization")
        at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:325) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5033$mk_worker__5089.doInvoke(worker.clj:389) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:500) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        ava.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/topic1/partitions at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokt backtype.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]

I am using kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1, apache-storm-0.9.4 and zookeeper-3.4.6.

There is no mismatch zookeeper jar version in kafka and cluster.

Please help me here.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure topic1 exists in kafka and you can read from it using a console consumer, I have seen org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for ... when the topic did not exist when the storm topology is deployed.

Also can you post some code on how you have configured the kafka spout ?

Is this error sporadic or consistent?

Comment: got the solution,  you are right Raj Kalluri topic id was not available.